# MySQL error code #1064 near IF ELSE block when creating a Trigger Before Insert

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, triggers, sql-insert

I am trying to put a constraint on a database where if `generic_asset.type = 'raw'` then `generic_asset.atomic = 1` must be maintained. For this I wrote the following trigger of type `BEFORE INSERT`. Here is the snippet:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER generic_asset_check BEFORE INSERT ON generic_asset FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF NEW.type = 'raw' THEN
   BEGIN
       IF NEW.atomic = 0 THEN
           SET SQLSTATE = 'Sorry cannot insert';
       END IF;
   END IF;
END //


DELIMITER ;
```

Error is like:

```
#1064 - syntax error near 'SQLSTATE = 'Sorry cannot insert';
       END IF;
   END IF;
END' in line 6
```

(translated from French).

I tried various syntax but all seam not to work and also knowing that my changes are so little like changing double quotes, removing `BEGIN` with `END IF;`... So I know these turns are irreverent.

I revised syntax in many internet resources and official documentation, nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's `IF` statement does not take a `BEGIN` keyword. Also, if you want to raise an error from within the trigger, you need `SIGNAL`. Finally, these two nested conditions can be flattened.

Consider:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER generic_asset_check BEFORE INSERT ON generic_asset FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF NEW.type = 'raw' AND NEW.atomic = 0 THEN
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Sorry cannot insert';
   END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9caMfn8e1vKp9QgERs8b43/0)**